# Are these two relations on integers partial orders?

Tags: partial-order

Are the following relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ defined on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers partial orders? (A partial order is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.)

1. $a$ $R_1$ $b$ if and only if $a = 2b$.
2. $a$ $R_2$ $b$ if and only if $a^2|b$.

Would someone help me understand?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what the question is.

Comment: Is your question "Are the relations in 1 and/or 2 partial orders?"

Comment: @Merbs Why would you edit the question if you didn't understand what was being asked? If possible, it makes even less sense now.

Comment: Nothing CS-specific here, so more appropriate for math.stackexchange.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus partial order is an important field in CS.

Comment: @Patrick87, because I couldn't even read it [before I edited it](http://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/7184/revisions). Also the request was a bit more forward than I imagine the OP intended it to be. What would the appropriate action have been?

Comment: @Merbs In general, you should not edit a question you do not understand, particularly when the state you leave it in is incomprehensible. If you feel the question is incomprehensible, you should ask for clarification or vote to close. Who knows what was being asked?

Comment: @AJed The binary number system is extremely important in CS.

Comment: @Bartek $A = Z$ and $A \in Z$ mean different things.

Comment: @AJed Actual chips to run stuff on are very important for CS; nevertheless, questions about them are offtopic here.

Comment: @Raphael sorting is a CS topic, isnt ? - then i guess it s the same for partial order. DAG's is a CS topic ? - partial order are used to analyze it in many cases. Relations and order belongs to this forum in my opinion. I know a company that built commercial systems based on partial order ideas. Second, this question has been answered. Then it could be a chance to learn.

Comment: @AJed: Not every tool is a topic. Would you call combinatorics a CS topic? Number theory? That said, we entertain other pure maths questions (e.g. about asymptotics) so I see no harm in keeping this.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at all the different criteria (reflexivity, symmetry or antisymmetry, and transitivity) for the first relations, $aR_1b\Leftrightarrow a=2b$ :

a) Is it reflexive, or antireflexive, or neither?  For this we want to test $aR_1a$ — or in other words, whether $a=2a$.  This *can* hold if $a=0$, but otherwise it never holds.  So on $\Bbb{Z}$ the relation is neither reflexive nor antireflexive; but on $\Bbb{N}$ (the set of 'whole numbers', not counting 0) it would be antireflexive, since $a=2a$ can never hold there.

b) Is it symmetric, or antisymmetric, or neither?  Here we want to compare $aR_1b$ and $bR_1a$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct values; in other words, can we have both $a=2b$ and $b=2a$?  Dividing by 2, the latter is equivalent to $a=\frac{1}{2}b$, and the only way we can have both $a=2b$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}b$ is to have $b=0$, in which case $a=0$ — but since we said that $a$ and $b$ had to be distinct, this can't hold.  In other words, if we have $aR_1b$ for $a\neq b$ we can never have $bR_1a$; the relation is antisymmetric.

c) Is it transitive?  (Note that we never ask about 'antitransitivity', even though the concept hypothetically makes sense).  For this, we want to figure out if $(aR_1b)\wedge(bR_1c)\implies(aR_1c)$ — in other words, if $a=2b$ and $b=2c$, is $a=2c$?  Well, if $a=2b$ and $b=2c$, then we have $a=2b=2(2c)=4c$, so it's definitely not the case that $a=2c$; this relation is *not* transitive.

Since this has the feel of homework, I'll let you do the second one yourself, but it should be relatively straightforward (as long as you know a little bit about divisibility).  For looking at reflexivity, you'll have special cases again where $a=0$ and also where $a=\pm1$ to keep an eye out for; for symmetry you should be able to use the divisibility to say something about the relative order of $a$ and $b$; and for transitivity you should try to figure out how to 'staple' the two conditions $a^2|b$ and $b^2|c$ together to see if you can figure out whether $a^2|c$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the answer to my comment is yes,

1. The first is not a partial order, since it is not reflexive; in general, it is not true that $a = 2a$ (consider the case $a \neq 0$).
2. The second is not a partial order, since it is not reflexive; in general, it is not true that $a^2 | a$ (consider the case $a > 1$).

Comment: Since both cases fail on reflexivity, one wonders whether the partial order perhaps is meant to be a strict partial order?

Comment: @HendrikJan Hey man, I just answer 'em as I reads 'em.